# I get a NoSuchElementException in my selenium code unless I use a breakpoint

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, breakpoints

I have a problem at Selenium code which is that when I run code with a breakpoint it works well, without a breakpoint I get an exception...

this is the code:

```
IWebElement myField4 = driver.FindElement(By.Name("login_1method"));
myField4.Click();

IWebElement myField5 = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div.content-wrapper.landing-page > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > article > section > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a"));
myField5.Click();
```

The code gives an error at `myfield5` without a breakpoint but works if it pauses at a breakpoint on the first line.

The error

> NoSuchElementException was unhandled

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536954/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-nosuchelementexception-in-selenium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebDriver is running to fast. You can use explicit wait with [expected conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) to allow the WebElement to load

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("body > div.content-wrapper.landing-page > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > article > section > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a"))).Click();
```

`wait.Until` returns the element you where waiting for, so you can use it to send the click.