# WebDriver Sample with Java error - Encountered "WDS"

Tags: selenium, webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using java as scripting language in JMeter 3.0 and jmeter-plugins-webdriver-1.4.0.jar. When I run my script which is supposed to open a browser and go to gmail.com, and sign in. I get the following error:

```
ERROR - com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler: In file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium; 

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui;  WDS.sampleRe . . . 

Encountered "WDS" at line 5, column 1.in inline evaluation of: 
import org.openqa.selenium; 

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui;  

WDS.sampleRe . . . '' at line number 5 

ERROR - com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler: In file: inline evaluation of: 

import org.openqa.selenium.*; import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;  import o . . . '' Encountered "WebElement" at line 9, column 1.
     in inline evaluation of: 

import org.openqa.selenium.*; import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*; 

 import o . . .  at line number 9
```

Here are my 2 scripts :

Open Browser:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;


WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://gmail.com')
// login details
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

LogIn:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;


WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()


WebElement userIdElement = WDS.browser.findElement(By.id(("username"));
userIdElement.sendKeys('${email}');
WebElement pwdElement = WDS.browser.findElement(By.id("password"));
pwdElement.sendKeys('${pwd}');
WebElement signIn = WDS.browser.findElement(By.id("login"))
signIn.click();
// login details
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems with your test

1. Missing semicolons
2. Unbalanced parentheses
3. Given Java language you cannot access JMeter Variables like `${email}`
4. Invalid WebElement IDs

Here is example fixed code:

- Open Browser

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.*;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;


  WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
  WDS.browser.get("http://gmail.com");
  // login details
  WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
  ```
- Login

  ```
  import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService;
  import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables;


  import org.openqa.selenium.*;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;

  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;


  WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
  JMeterVariables vars = JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables();


  WebElement userIdElement = WDS.browser.findElement(By.id("Email"));
  userIdElement.sendKeys(new String[]{vars.get("email")});
  WebElement nextButton = WDS.browser.findElement(By.id("next"));
  nextButton.click();
  WebElement pwdElement = WDS.browser.findElement(By.id("Passwd"));
  pwdElement.sendKeys(new String[]{vars.get("pwd")});
  WebElement signIn = WDS.browser.findElement(By.id("signIn"));
  signIn.click();
  // login details
  WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
  ```

Also consider using [Explicit Waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) as it is quite unlikely your that your browser loads pages immediately and hence you'll get tons of [NoSuchElementExceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536954/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-nosuchelementexception-in-selenium)

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide for more information on using the WebDriver Sampler in JMeter tests.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this sendKeys method
Eg: WDS.browser.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys(new String[]{vars.get("abcd")});

so, instead of passing abcd, it is passing NULL

Answer (score 0):

I used sendKeys method Example:

```
WDS.browser.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys( new String[] { "abcd" } );
```

doing so resolved the passing of NULL.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).