# Python Selenium add content to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, selenium, pandas, web-scraping

I am trying to loop over a **list** of zip codes to scrape content on  [this url](http://kadastralekaart.com/)  but am faced with error such as `TimeoutException` and `StaleElementReferenceException`

How do I overcome this issues? How do I loop through the list and be able to get the all data into a pandas dataframe?

Her is what I have tried so far

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

zip_key = ['1065VL', '1087AZ', '1083CX', '1025AS']

for z in zip_key:
#     print (z)

    url = 'see url above'
    chrome_driver = 'As usual'

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)

    # load the url above
    driver.get(url)

    # =================================
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

    driver.find_element_by_id('searchBox').send_keys(z)

    driver.find_element_by_id('searchButton').click()

    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'listElementContent0'))).click()

    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.leaflet-popup-content b')))

    # =================================
    popup = driver.find_element_by_class_name("leaflet-popup-content")

    time.sleep(30)

    # =================================
    string1 = popup.text
    string1 = string1.split('\n')

    time.sleep(10)

    # =================================
    df_text = [{'A': string1[0], 'B': string1[1], 'C': string1[2], 'D': string1[3]}]

    df = pd.DataFrame(df_text)

    df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace('Kadastrale aanduiding: ', '')
    df['B'] = df['B'].str.replace("Kadastrale grootte \(m2\) : ", '')
    df['D'] = df['D'].str.replace('Perceelnummer: ', '')


#     driver.quit()

df
```