# NoSuchElementException: could not click the div element

Tags: python, selenium, element

```
<td role="presentation" valign="top" class=" x-trigger-cell x-unselectable" style="width:28px;" id="ext-gen1147">
<div class="x-trigger-index-0 x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger x-form-trigger-first rp-icon-expanded" role="presentation" id="ext-gen1146">
</div></td>
```

im trying to click this div elementbut throwing exception.My code is:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='ext-gen1146']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ext-gen1147']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='x-trigger-index-0 x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger x-form-trigger-first rp-icon-expanded' and @id='ext-gen1146']")
```

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='ext-gen1147']"}   (Session
>   info: chrome=80.0.3987.163)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below solution and check your element is not dynamic and its not inside the iframe, if its in iframe then you have to switch to it and then click on your eelement.

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ext-gen1147"))).click()
```

or

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "x-trigger-index-0 x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger x-form-trigger-first rp-icon-expanded"))).click()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

To switch to iframe you can use below code, Make sure you have only one iframe or else you can use ID/Name of iframe to identify correct element before switching:

```
 iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')))
 driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Comment: check your element is not dynamic and its not inside the iframe

Comment: i checked already id is not dynamic and it's in iframe only so i switched using driver.switch_to.frame(0). i official url so i couldn't share..please help me

Comment: Are you sure you are on correct iframe and you dont have multiple iframes associated with your web page?

Comment: yes..other elements i can access within this same iframe ,only this is causing error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211870/discussion-between-dipak-bachhav-and-divya-mani).

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you need to wait for visibility first, maybe this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/19537085/2069610... for example:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<"ext-gen1146>));
```

Comment: I could see the elements are loaded in DOM, even after loaded it shows exception

Answer (score 0):

To click on dynamic element Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following `css selector`.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.rp-icon-expanded[id^='ext-gen'][role='presentation']"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: @DivyaMani : I have just modified the css selector a bit.Could you try again?

Answer (score 0):

you can try Actions class to click on the expected element -

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.click(element).build().perform();
```

if this also not works try using JavascriptExecutor

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor..executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```